# Split two sticked dates into two different rows in R

Tags: r, date, split

After having tidied a dataframe in R, I obtain a date column where, sometimes, dates are sticked together.
How can I split those concatenated dates into new rows?

```
date
6/01/220
20/03/202021/02/2020
15/04/202016/04/2020
9/05/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "6/01/220" was a typo, this will work:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(date = str_extract_all(date, "\\d{1,2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}")) %>% 
  unnest(date)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   date      
#>   <chr>     
#> 1 6/01/2020 
#> 2 20/03/2020
#> 3 21/02/2020
#> 4 15/04/2020
#> 5 16/04/2020
#> 6 9/05/2020
```

the important part is the RegEx (`"\\d{1,2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}"`).

- `\\d{1,2}` means a number between 1 and 2 characters long
- `\\d{2}` means a number exactly 2 characters long
- `\\d{4}` means a number exactly 4 characters long

There are tons of tutorials for Regex. I always recommend this [cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Yes it seems to work fine thank you. Thanks for the Regex explanation

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it and upvote it as a signal for others who have a similar question. And for me to earn some reputation points :)